# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process - using static class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get the error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" when I attempt to delete the files I just uploaded (this is at least a few seconds after the files were uploaded, so I am sure they are finished writing). Any ideas why this occurs? PS: The thumbnails I generate delete without a problem, but the originals are locked somehow.

```
            var FileExt = Path.GetExtension(photo.File.FileName);
            var FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + photo.ClientId), photo.PhotoId.ToString()) + FileExt;
            photo.File.SaveAs(FilePath);
            var ThumbFilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + photo.ClientId),photo.PhotoId.ToString() + "_thumbnail") + FileExt;
            PhotoTools.MakeThumbnail(FilePath, ThumbFilePath, 0.15);
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
```

Inside a PhotoTools class...

```
    public static void MakeThumbnail(string ImgIn, string ImgOut, double Percent)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(ImgIn);
        double Width = img.Width*Percent;
        double Height = img.Height*Percent;
        MakeThumbnail(ImgIn, ImgOut, (int)Width, (int)Height);
    }
```

Delete function...

```
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Client client = db.Clients.Find(id);
        db.Clients.Remove(client);
        db.SaveChanges();
        if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + id)))
        {
            Directory.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + id,true);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Show the other MakeThumbnail code. Pretty sure you're not Disposing a class.

Comment: You said _"when I attempt to delete the files I just uploaded"_ which could use a little bit of clarifying. Because there is no `delete` in your code for the file or the thumbnail, it sounds like you might be talking about deleting these files using Windows Explorer or similar?  Is that correct or...?

Comment: Are you deleting the files during the same request where you created them?

Comment: I updated the code to show deletion method, for future reference. The method was called separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your MakeThumbnail methods, make sure you're calling `Dispose()` on the `Image` types. That or use the using syntax:

```
using (Image img = Image.FromFile(ImgIn))
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: +1 it be good if you can explain to the OP how the GC has a "root ref" to the file from loading an unmanaged resource and this is causing the file to be locked.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - not sure I know enough about that to explain it. Can you edit my post with it or post here so I can upvote?