# FileUpload control in asp/VB.net cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

Error message:

The process cannot access the file 'C:\SampleProjectName\mytestcsv.csv' because it is being used by another process.

I am trying to read numerous files (CSV, XML, HTML) in asp/VB.net using the fileupload (file upload) control.

I'm saving the file using Server.MapPath so I can process the file in another procedure.  It's very odd, but sometimes I can browse and upload the same file over and over with no issues, but sometimes it immediately fails.

I've found that I can ultimately kill the WebDev.WebServer40.exe it releases whatever lock is present.  This is annoying, but fine for my debugging... but unacceptable for endusers.

My fileupload code:

```
If fuImport.HasFile Then

        If (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("myhtml.html"))) Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("myhtml.html"))
        End If

        Dim dtFromHTML As New Data.DataTable
        Dim dtFromSQL As New Data.DataTable

        Try
            fuImport.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("mytestcsv.csv"))

            'Process data here
            ProcessCSVData(Server.MapPath("mytestcsv.csv"))

        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write("error: " & ex.Message)

        Finally
            fuImport.PostedFile.InputStream.Flush()
            fuImport.PostedFile.InputStream.Close()
            fuImport.FileContent.Dispose()

        End Try

'Other things happen here

Else
     Response.Write("no file...")

End If
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileShare.Read to read a file even if it is opened exclusively by an another process.

Comment: So would you even recommend that I save the file then?  As regardless of whether or not my import program actually reads it, once it gets to the "If file exists, delete" portion it will fail.  Besides that, is the fileupload control actually updating the file if it's still opened exclusively by another process?

Answer (score 0):

You may not be releasing the file in your code for access. You should use the keyword "using".

Read this post: 
[The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process - using static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015468/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process)

and this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx

I am not a VB.NET coder but try something along the lines of:

```
Using {fuImport.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("mytestcsv.csv")) }
           ProcessCSVData(Server.MapPath("mytestcsv.csv"))
End Using
```

The next procedure that uses file...

Comment: The syntax I found asks that you define the datatype, which I'm not sure about so I guessed a few, but that doesn't seem to matter.  I'm getting an error saying that the "Expression does not produce a value" which makes sense.
    Using myfile As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload = fuImport.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("mycsv.csv")
 ProcessCSVData(Server.MapPath("mytestcsv.csv"))
    End Using


I've also tried exactly as you listed (less the C# syntax) and it produces the same error.
    Using (fuImport.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("myhtml.html")))

Answer (score 0):

Try closing input stream before accessing the file:

**UPDATED** To use temp filename

```
Dim sTempName = Path.GetRandomFileName

fuImport.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(sTempName))

'close before accessing saved file
fuImport.PostedFile.InputStream.Close()

'Process data here
ProcessCSVData(Server.MapPath(sTempName)
```

Comment: I attempted to re-import the file 3 times, on the third try it yielded the same error on the "      System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("myhtml.html"))" portion.  When it processes the file, I'm guessing it reacquires a lock... should I be loading the file for processing a different way?

Comment: You mean that the process `ProcessCSVData` itself is locking the file? If so, release resources associated with the file (close, dispose etc.) as soon as processing is done (file read/written etc.) Also: Is this a multiuser environment when the same process is used by multiple users? Is the file deleted right after it's processed?

Comment: Also I see that u delete file `myhtml.html` but write into file `mytestcsv.csv` is this on purpose? If so, when does `mytestcsv.csv` gets deleted?

Comment: That's a typo when pasting and attempting to make it "generic".  The real version has the same name.

Comment: Instead of using hardcoded filename like `mytestcsv.csv` use `Path.GetRandomFileName` (I've updated my answer) - this way there will be no file collision